# How can I find my Macbook if it was stolen and its offline?

Tags: macbook-pro

Someone stole my MacBook. How can I find it if it’s offline. I have its serial number if it helps. Please if someone knows, tell me. I have really important stuff on it and I can’t get it back. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51652/can-a-macbook-pro-be-tracked-when-disconnected-from-the-internet https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80394/lost-my-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-how-do-i-find-out-if-find-my-idevice-is

Comment: So sorry to hear, we have a couple questions that explain how this works and what your chances are. If you want to edit this to have some of the specifics and explain why Apple’s documentation or the questions here don’t help you - please go ahead and make an edit to the body of the question. that lets high rep users review your changes and possibly reopen it if this isn’t a duplicate question